# Flask Login - @login_manager.token_loader not being called

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am trying to use a token to authenticate users.

I have managed to get the process working using:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    from models import User
    return User.get(userid)
```

However I don't know how to get the process working when using a `token`.

In my `views.py` file, I have:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, url_for, render_template, session

@login_manager.token_loader
def load_token(token):

    # Check token and return user
```

When I login a user:

```
def _do_login_user(user):
    # User must have been authenticated
    if not user: raise_error('user does not exist', 'A user with this email address does not exist', 404)     

    # Check if user account is enabled
    if not user.is_active:
        raise_error('inactive account', 'Your account has not been enabled. Check your email Inbox and Spam folders for the confirmation email', 401)

    # Use Flask-Login to sign in user
    login_user(user)

    return json.dumps({"data":{"success":"true", "message":"You have logged in successfully!"}})
```

**User Model**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    def get_auth_token(self):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in = 6000)
        return s.dumps({'id': self.id, 'password': self.password})
```

At what point should I be calling `User.get_auth_token()` and should I manually be setting this token in the `session`?

Finally when does `@login_manager.token_loader` get called?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

``@login_manager.token_loader` is all about "remember me" functionality.

It will only be called when a browser visits your site without a session cookie and the user previously was logged in with `login_user(user, remember=True)`.

You can probably stimulate flask-login to call your token_loader decorated function by:

- logging in with 'remember me'
- close your browser
- open the browser again and navigate to a 'login_required' page

...or use something like the code at the end of this answer.

You do not need to call `User.get_auth_token()` yourself. Flask-login will call it when you call `login_user(user, remeber=True)` and have defined a `@login_manager.token_loader`

Take a look at `LoginManager._set_cookie` and `LoginManager._load_from_cookie` to see how Flask-Login goes about doing all this.

Your `_do_login_user` function invokes `login_user` without `remember=True` thus none of this "remember me" functionality is invoked.

Below is some code which should illustrate when the functions in question are called:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required

app = Flask('foo')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abcd'
login_manager = LoginManager(app)


class User(UserMixin):
    def get_id(self):
        return 1

    def get_auth_token(self):
        print("get_auth_token called")
        return 'my_auth_token'


@login_manager.token_loader
def my_token_loader(token):
    print("my_token_loader called")
    return User()


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    login_user(User(), remember=True)
    return ''


@app.route('/protected')
@login_required
def protected():
    return ''


with app.test_client() as tc:
    # login will set session cookie as well as remember me cookie
    # User.get_auth_token will be called because we have defined a token_loader
    tc.get('/login')

    # clear the session cookie so the next request will use remember me
    tc.cookie_jar.clear_session_cookies()

    # our token_loader function should be called now as Flask-Login attempts to
    # log us in with the remember me cookie
    tc.get('/protected')
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I have done as you said and it appears to be working to an extent. The problem I currently have is that if I `Login`, `Access Protected Page` and then `Access Protected Page` for the second time immediately after doing it the 1st time, I get an `internal server error` saying I need to implement `user_loader`. I also notice that the `session` variable has been set again. Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Giri What you describe is expected behaviour. Yes, you do need to implement an `user_loader` and `User.get_id` in your application. `token_loader` is only concerned with 'remember me' functionality. You define one when you want to "increase the security of your remember cookies". Flask-Login uses `token_loader` to build a regular session which contains an id generated by `User.get_id` and sent to `user_loader` on subsequent page loads.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks Jeremy!

Comment: I don't find `login_manager.token_loader` in flask-login, should it be `login_manager.request_loader`?

Answer (score 0):

I had my bad time trying to make this work as well and then I gave up using the normal user_loader, the only thing I can suggest is having a look here [flask-login](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login.py#L420) and check the actual code, from that you see that it adds the user_id in the session so you don't have to take care of it.

Anyway I spent quite a lot of time trying to make it work and in the end i opted for something similar to this [jwt and flask-login](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/253)

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(token):
    try:
        id = jwt.decode(token, current_app.config.get(
            'KEY', None))['_id']
        return user_functions.get_user_by_id(id, token)
    except (ServiceUnavailable, ServiceResponseError) as e:
        current_app.logger.exception(e.message)
        return None



class Login(MethodView):

    methods = ['GET', 'POST']

    def post(self):
        form = LoginForm(request.form)
        registered_user = form.validate()
        if not registered_user:
            return render_template('pages/login.html', login_form=form), 403
        login_user(registered_user, remember=False)
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('public.index'))
```

not sure how helpful it is, but when you run out of patience is worth a read